# New theorem with svmono

Tags: environments, theorems

I have problems with the definition of the new environments which should be the same as the `theorem` evironment but **unnumbered**. If I write:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap,oribibl]{svmono} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\spnewtheorem*{theo}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}[Faltings, 1983]
bla bla
\end{theo}

\end{documents}
```

I obtain the title as an emphatized text, and not the usual theorem evironment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an error in the definition of `\spnewtheorem*`. Use

```
\spnewtheorem*{theo}{Theorem}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\itshape}
```

For strange reasons, when a numbered theorem is called, `svmono` eventually executes `\@spnewtheorem`, which expands to

```
\trivlist \item [\hskip \labelsep {#3#1\ #2\@thmcounterend }]#4
```

where `#3` is the third argument to `\spnewtheorem` and `#4` is the fourth one. Thus, in the case of `\spnewtheorem{foo}{\bfseries}{\itshape}`, `\itshape` is only applied to the theorem body. With an unnumbered theorem, the macro is `\@Begintheorem`, that expands to

```
#3\trivlist \item [\hskip \labelsep {#2#1\@thmcounterend }]
```

where `#2` is the third argument to `\spnewtheorem*` and `#3` is the fourth one. So, in your case, `\itshape` is executed before typesetting the theorem label.

Of course the definition of `\@Begintheorem` should be

```
\trivlist \item [\hskip \labelsep {#2#1\@thmcounterend }]#3
```